# FFMPEG + h264_nvenc + -force_key_frames

Tags: ffmpeg

FFmpeg omit option -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*5)" when use codec h264_nvenc. Why ? Is a bug?

```sh
fmpeg -v verbose -hwaccel auto -i granito.mp4 \
-vf "hwupload_cuda,scale_npp=w=-2:h=720:format=yuv420p:interp_algo=lanczos,hwdownload,format=yuv420p" \
-vcodec h264_nvenc -zerolatency 1 -gpu 0 -profile:v main -level 4.2 \
-preset llhq -bf:v 2 -rc vbr_hq -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1m -acodec aac -ar 22050 \
-b:a 64k -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 0 \
-force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*5)" -sc_threshold 0 -f hls index.m3u8
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have to set `forced_idr` if you want a random access point, as opposed to an intra-coded picture.

```
ffmpeg ... -vcodec h264_nvenc ... -forced-idr 1 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*5)"
```